# javascript breadcrumb geting it on body of page

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have breadcrumb code from schema in javascript, I don't know how do I get it showing on the page whether it's done by php or javascript not sure.

Here's the code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [{
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
                "@id": "https://example.com/dresses",
                "name": "Dresses"
            }
        }, {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
                "@id": "https://example.com/dresses/real",
                "name": "Real Dresses"
            }
        }]
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What are you trying to render?

Comment: @Shilly i have a breadcrumb in javascript dear i want to get it showing the page

Comment: Yes but what is this breadcrumb? A <ul> list tag you need to create? Is it a list of hyperlink to example.com/dresses? Do you have this exact snippet inside your code, or does it arrive from an ajax call?

Comment: @Shilly sorry i have fixed. thanks for your time and answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Javascript itself since you already have the data in JS

define a div in the HTML

```
<div id="bc"></div>
```

Then run the JS

```
itemListElement.forEach(function(ele){
document.getElementById("bc").innerHTML = document.getElementbyId("bc").innerHTML + " > " + ele.item.name;
})
```

I have not written the full code, but this should give you an idea.